# Forms Authentication SSO Logout Issue due to duplicate cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, global-asax

I am using forms authentication to handle SSO across *.mydomain.com
Upon login i create a non-persistant cookie with the ticket embedded in it and set it's domain to .mydomain.com.

However the problem is that when i visit any website on the domain, i find there are two cookie with the same name but with different domains. :

1> site1.mydomain.com [1st Forms Auth Cookie]  **duplicate cookie**

2> .mydomain.com[2nd Forms Auth cookie]

[image]

The 1st Cookie is not created by me.Also it isn't secure.

Upon logout i successfully clear my 2nd Cookie.

However, the 1st cookie remains and for a user it appears that he is still logged in to *site1* . This happpens because i check for the existence of the cookie with the same name and surely the 1st cookie is wrongly assumed to be the Forms Auth Cookie. I cannot check the domain property because in the Request the information about the domain is *null* .

My issue is how is the second website-specific domain cookie is getting created.
If i cannot avoid this, is there a workaround?

**UPDATE** : The encrypted value stored by this faulty cookie is updated on each request i make on the website,while the encrypted value in my Auth Cookie remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSFT Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

*"The Add method allows duplicate cookies in the cookie collection. Use the Set method to ensure the uniqueness of cookies in the cookie collection."*

After renewing my Forms Authentication ticket i was doing :

```
Response.Cookies.Add(..);
```

Thus a new duplicate cookie was getting generated.

To fix this do :

```
Response.Cookies.Set(..);
```

If you were like me you would have expected ASP.Net to replace the old cookie with the new one.